# Use a command over a set of files and save results

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a set of files in a directory

```
test1.in
test2.in
test3.in
test4.in
...
```

I have written a conversion tool to extract some data from those files and save it into another file.

I want to run that conversion tool for each file and save the results into different output files

```
./tool -i test1.in -i test1.out
./tool -i test2.in -o test2.out
```

I have seen a lot of answer to iterate on the files and run the desired command for each file, but I am not sure how to specify the output.

```
for file in dir/*.in; do
    ./tool -i file -o ???
done
```

How can I create a name for the output file?

Comment: Read up in the bash manual about all the nifty things you can with parameter expansion.

Comment: Your example looks odd! You mean you want to overwrite `test2.out` each time?

Comment: ups, that's a typo. Ill correct it. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for file in dir/*.in; do
    ./tool -i "$file" -o "${file%.*}".out
done
```

`"${file%.*}"` represents the value of `$file` before the last `.` (See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion, look for `${parameter%word}`).

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? I have added `echo` to see the output file and its always outputing in.out

Comment: No Wait. I'll test and update..

Comment: Done. I think this works now..